# How to disable the quickfix window?

Tags: vimrc, quickfix, python

[image: Screenshot_20201111_201729]

This is the display when I typed `:AsyncRun -mode=term -pos=bottom ~/.anaconda/bin/python %`.

But if I set:

```
filetype plugin on
map <F5> :call RunPython()<CR>
function! RunPython()
    exec "w"
    if &filetype == 'python'
        if search("@profile")
            exec "AsyncRun kernprof -l -v %"
            exec "copen"
            exec "wincmd p"
        elseif search("set_trace()")
            exec "!~/.anaconda/bin/python %"
        else
            exec "AsyncRun -mode=term -pos=bottom ~/.anaconda/bin/python %"
            exec "copen"
            exec "wincmd p"
        endif
    endif
endfunc
```

in my `.vimrc`, it will display the quickfix window which I do not want.

[image: Screenshot_20201111_202200]

How to disable the quickfix window?

Comment: Your function includes `copen`, which opens the quickfix window... also, the executes are not needed.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted them and everything went OK

Answer (score 1):

Remove the lines that open the quickfix list (`:copen`).

Aside—if you use `:execute` for simple Ex commands, it’s usually enough to do just the command (so just `:copen`, `:wincmd p`, etc.). Even the colon’s aren’t necessary in most places.

Answer (score 0):

Now it looks laike this:

```
filetype plugin on
map <F5> :call RunPython()<CR>
function! RunPython()
    exec "w"
    if &filetype == 'python'
        if search("@profile")
            exec "AsyncRun kernprof -l -v %"
        elseif search("set_trace()")
            exec "!~/.anaconda/bin/python %"
        else
            exec "AsyncRun -mode=term -pos=bottom ~/.anaconda/bin/python %"
        endif
    endif
endfunc
```